# sql join two tables with 0 values

Tags: sql, join

I'm having some trouble joining the contents of two tables. Here's the current situation and the table should be shown as result

Table a

```
id | income             
----------              
1 | 100                 
2 | 200                 
3 | 300                 
4 | 400                 
5 | 500
```

Table b

```
id | outcome
----------
1 | 10   
2 | 20   
6 | 60   
7 | 70   
3 | 30
```

Result table

```
id | income | outcome | balance
--------------------------------
1  | 100    | 10      | 100-10=90
2  | 200    | 20      | 200-20=180
3  | 300    | 30      | 300-30=270
4  | 400    |  0      | 400-0=400
5  | 500    |  0      | 500-0=500
6  |   0    | 60      | 0-60=-60
7  |   0    | 70      | 0-70=-70
```

- every id should be disctinct in the result table
- income and outcome should be shown in the result table. if the id is not in one of the table income or outcome should be 0
- calculation of balance column: income-outcome

Please provide code, without using the statement

```
where id not in (select id from ...)
```

because `not in` statement is not supported by the system I am using.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: outer-join is the answer, you just have to know how to convert 'Null' to zero

Comment: Does your system support FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: It would help to know **what concrete database system** you're using !

Comment: yes, i see this problem too. It is so called -abap cds view- and many features are not yet implemented in it. Better i will try the solution below tomorrow (bcs, i don't have access today) and write here the result. I am not sure, if this system supports full outer join. Pls don't investigate now your time, i will come to back to you tomorow. Thanks

Comment: I've checked it, i can work with the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using a `full outer join`:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id,
       coalesce(a.income, 0) as income,
       coalesce(b.outcome, 0) as outcome,
       (coalesce(a.income, 0) - coalesce(b.outcome, 0)) as balance
from tablea a full outer join
     tableb b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

You don't specify the database.  `Full outer join` is ANSI-standard and supported by most databases.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried it at mssql, and it is working well. I am going to try it tomorrow in the real system tomorrow. As i mentioned above; the system is abap cds view and i am not sure, if it supports **Full outer join**. As i can see here, it is not supported (http://bit.ly/1Eq5fL5) . I will write to you the result here. If the system doesn't support it really, do you have any other idea? Thanks